# Xamarin Forms Deep linking and adding an app icon to phone dialer like whatsapp call

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, deep-linking

I have a task where I'm expected to develop an android app that has chat and calling features. That is not a problem but the problem is that I have a feature where I must add the app icon to the default phone dialer such that when a user is on the phone dialer or contacts list, my app icon will appear beside the phone call icon as an option to call just like you can make a Whatsapp call directly from your contact list. attached to this question is a sample of the screenshot

---

[image]